# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5.7

Im getting this error when I try to save data to mysql using Laravel 5, other forms and save() methods work fine but this one:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'datatest.about_category' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `about_category` (`about_id`, `category_id`) values (11, 4))

Here is my Controller store method:

```
public function store(AboutRequest $request)
{
    $about = new About();
    $about->title = $request->title;
    $about->body = $request->body;
    $about->save();
    $about->categories()->attach(request('category'));
    return redirect(route('abouts.create'));
}
```

And here is my model:

About.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class About extends Model
{
    public  $table = "abouts";
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Category .php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = "categories";

    public  $fillable = ['id' , 'name'];

    public function abouts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(About::class);
    }
}
```

For abouts table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('abouts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

For categories table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your many-to-many relationship requires three tables: `abouts`, `categories`, and `about_category`. You haven't created the `about_category` table:

```php
Schema::create('about_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('about_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('about_id')->references('id')->on('abouts');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
});
```

Comment: How to Share the migration for the pivot table?

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi I don't understand the question. Do you have a migration that creates the `about_category` table?

Comment: No I do not forger to run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: I updated my post and I have two tables and migrations.

Comment: I did not create `about_category` table yet.

Comment: I get this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`datatest`.`about_category`, CONSTRAINT `about_category_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `about_category` (`about_id`, `category_id`) values (1, 4))`

Comment: That sounds like a new error, and you should probably ask a new question for it. Are you sure that Category 4 exists in your database, or About 1? Make sure both models are saved before attaching relationships.