# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::categories does not exist

Tags: laravel-5.7

I want to display categories where `id` = 1

```
public function index ()
{
    $abouts = About::all();
    $webDesigns = $abouts->categories()->where('id', '1');
    return view('Home.index', compact('webDesigns'));
}
```

But I get this error

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::categories does not exist.

How to this work? OR What am I missing?

Comment: I'm guessing categories is a hasMany so you need to call it on a builder but calling `::all()` gives a collection, have you tried it with `$abouts = About::query();`

Comment: I replaced to `query` but my problem did not solve.

Comment: I followed already in my post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494782/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-laravel-5-7

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you add a relation between the 2 models.

I asume that it's a many to many relation.

In About model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
}
```

Additional info: The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) for relations.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```php
$webDesigns = $abouts->categories()->where('id', '1')->get();
```

or

```php
$webDesigns = $abouts->categories->where('id', '1');
```